# sql delete statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a .cs file, in which I'm looking into a db and a site for specific IDs.
And if the ID on the site is not in db (yet) it saves it into db.
Easy as that.

But what if the ID is in the db and NOT on the page. How to check for that. And how to delete it if its not on the site anymore.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks

Sebastian

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? Post some of you code for further info? What are you current sql queries? Are they being limited so the values don't appear on the pages?

Comment: If you have full control over the DB via your web pages, you should be able to prevent this to happen (delete the record while it is deleted on the page).

Comment: Do you need to do both of these things in the same query/procedure, or are they two separate tasks?

Comment: I don't have the current code here. But its like this.
I get an id from a fb json, and checks if its in db. If its not, the sql adds it to the db, if its already inside, it doesn't do anything.
But what if someone deletes a post on a fb wall, which the id of is already in the db, but the post is no longer on the wall.
So i don't want that post to be inside the table.

Is that better?
TY

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you would need to do a pre-check. So, assuming that from the FB wall you have the wall's 'master' id and you relate all posts in the wall to that id in your database, you first grab all post ids for the wall and check against your database. If they exist and if you have one in your database that is no longer on the wall, simply delete it. Then move on with your regular insertion.

Say, all of your data looks something like this:

```
FBWall {
    WallId  1,
    Posts = Posts[4] {
        Post { PostId = 1 },
        Post { PostId = 2 },
        Post { PostId = 4 },
        Post { PostId = 5 }
    }
}

DBWall {
    WallId = 1,
    Posts = Posts[4] {
        Post { PostId = 1 },
        Post { PostId = 2 },
        Post { PostId = 3 },
        Post { PostId = 4 }
    }
}
```

In the `FBWall` you have 4 posts with ids 1,2,4,5; in the `DBWall` you have 4 posts with ids 1,2,3,4. The difference is that post 3 from `FBWall` is gone so you need to delete it from `DBWall`. Also in `FBWall` you now have post 5 which is not in `DBWall` so you need to insert it.

Now that I think about it, the order of operations is irrelevant. You can either insert your new posts in the database first and then delete obsolete posts, or vice-versa. The end result is the same.

Hope this helps you a little.

Answer (score 1):

SQl Server 2008 has a MERGE statment, I suggest you look at it, you can in one statement delte bad records and update existing and insert new. It's pretty cool. Loot at it in Books Online'